# VIM: How can i know which highlight rule is being used for a keyword?

Tags: vim, editor

```
:colorscheme default
```

The filetype is php.

Can anyone help me to find out the highlight rule ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have something like this in my _gvimrc:

```
function! SyntaxBalloon()
    let synID   = synID(v:beval_lnum, v:beval_col, 0)
    let groupID = synIDtrans(synID)
    let name    = synIDattr(synID, "name")
    let group   = synIDattr(groupID, "name")
    return name . "\n" . group
endfunction

set balloonexpr=SyntaxBalloon()
set ballooneval
```

Comment: How can i know which syntax highlighter rule is being used for "class" keyword ? It's a php file.

Comment: This snippet shows the group name and the rule name in a pop-up balloon when you pause the cursor over the code.

Comment: @guru, there was a slight typo in the function name.

Comment: Is there any shortcut key to get the rule after pressing the key ? It's taking time.

Comment: You can do `set balloondelay=500` to set the delay to half a second.

Answer (score 7):

```
:hi[light]
```

will list all defined rules with a preview. You can also query single items:

```
:hi Keyword
```

To manually look up any syntax group *under the cursor*, there are choices. Mine is a function bounded to a key like this:

```
" Show syntax highlighting groups for word under cursor
nmap <F2> :call <SID>SynStack()<CR>
function! <SID>SynStack()
    if !exists("*synstack")
        return
    endif
    echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc
```

It'll list every syntax group the word belongs to.

Comment: How can i know which syntax highlighter rule is being used for "class" keyword ? It's a php file.

Comment: Where would i use this function, i used .vimrc file, should i add this function in .vimrc file ? and how can i use this function ?

Comment: Yes copy and paste progo's snippet in your .vimrc and restart vim. Hitting `F2` in NORMAL mode will show the info in the command line at the bottom of Vim.

Comment: I got some error after pressing <F2>, Error detected while processing function <SNR>24_SynStack:
line    4:
E116: Invalid arguments for function map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')),
E15: Invalid expression: map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')),
line    5:
E20: Mark not set

Comment: @guru, sounds like you've split the fourth line in two. Please keep the lines like here.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the following snippet tucked away for a while now, not sure where I got it.  This will set your `statusline` to show the highlight group of the word currently under the cursor:

```
:set statusline=%{synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line('.'),col('.'),1)),'name')}
```

This will update your `statusline` as you move around the file.

Comment: How can i know which syntax highlighter rule is being used for "class" keyword ? It's a php file.