# How do I find out which syntax command causes a particular word to be highlighted in vim?

Tags: r, vim

When I open a `.c` file in vim, and I type `TODO` inside a comment, it gets highlighted with yellow in vim. Note that this is not specified in my own `.vimrc`.

However, when I open a `.r` file, and I use `TODO` inside a comment, it does not get highlighted. I am trying to figure out how to make it so that `TODO` gets highlighted in `R` file as well, but I am not sure how to find the command that highlights `TODO` in `.c` files.

Answer (score 3):

The default `R` syntax script (`$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/r.vim`) links `rOKeyword`, `TODO`'s syntax group, to the `Title` highlight group.

The default `C` syntax script (`$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim`) links `cTodo`, `TODO`'s syntax group, to the `Todo` highlight group.

`TODO` is not highlighted in `R` files as in `C` files because it is not linked to the right highlight group.

I suggest you contact the maintainer and ask him to fix that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this helps?

[VIM: How can i know which highlight rule is being used for a keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893445/vim-how-can-i-know-which-highlight-rule-is-being-used-for-a-keyword/7893500#7893500)

Examine the troubling highlight classes, do a grep or ack by the names in the `.vim` files under `/syntax/` directories.